# [Vue warn]: Error compiling template when rendering `trix-editor's` value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-trix

I don't know why I keep on getting a value that's like this ...

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in
```

- Maybe because I have a trix-editor's value right there that contains html attributes like this

```html
:users="{"id":215,"full_name":"Orla Jones","alias":"Aliass","first_name":"Orla","middle_name":null,"last_name":"Jones","created_at":"2020-01-04 18:42:11","updated_at":"2020-01-04 18:42:11","status":"1","posted_by":40,"photo":"1578134531.jpeg","country_id":304,"contact_number":"+1 (191) 741-1593","residence":[],"profile":{"user_id":215,"birthplace":null,"country_last_seen":304,"birthdate":null,"last_seen":null,"eye_color":null,"weight_in_kilos":null,"height_in_feet_and_inches":null,"country_of_origin":null,"body_frame":null,"bounty":"300.00","created_at":"2020-01-04 18:42:11","updated_at":"2020-01-04 18:42:11","complete_description":"<blockquote><strong>In in aut aspernatur..&nbsp;<\/strong><\/blockquote><div><figure data-trix-attachment=\"{"contentType":"image\/jpeg","filename":"R__ihbyb_200x200.jpg","filesize":25417,"height":200,"href":"localhost\/storage\/WDcG3pxX6ThUwohKV1KEeeFVPDQ5GB4vixLZNRtp.jpeg?content-disposition=attachment","url":"localhost\/storage\/WDcG3pxX6ThUwohKV1KEeeFVPDQ5GB4vixLZNRtp.jpeg","width":200}\" data-trix-content-type=\"image\/jpeg\" data-trix-attributes=\"{"caption":"lorem.jpg","presentation":"gallery"}\" class=\"attachment attachment--preview attachment--jpg\"><a href=\"localhost\/storage\/WDcG3pxX6ThUwohKV1KEeeFVPDQ5GB4vixLZNRtp.jpeg?content-disposition=attachment\"><img src=\"localhost\/storage\/WDcG3pxX6ThUwohKV1KEeeFVPDQ5GB4vixLZNRtp.jpeg\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"><figcaption class=\"attachment__caption attachment__caption--edited\">lorem.jpg<\/figcaption><\/a><\/figure><br><br><br><br><\/div>","currency":"USD"}}"
```

Comment: You're using double quotes to delimit the ends of the attribute value but then also using double quotes within that value. How is the parser supposed to know when the value ends? You'll need to HTML encode it if you want to use it inline like that, though it may be more maintainable just to move it to a property of the component.

Comment: What do u mean ? this is how I did it :) `<users-view :users="{{ $users }}" inline-template>`

Comment: What do you mean by HTML encode @skirtle